# Why is Jack's answer sharp?

Tags: content-clauses

'Well, Jack, and where are you off to?' said the man.
'I'm going to market to sell our cow there.'
'Oh, you look the proper sort of chap to sell cows,' said the man; 'I wonder if you know how many beans make five.'
'**Two in each hand and one in your mouth**,' says Jack, as sharp as a needle.
'Right you are,' says the man.

This content is from "Jack and the Beanstalk" in English fairy tales.

I couldn't understand why Jack's answer "Two in each hand and one in your mouth" is sharp. Could you teach me? And does this word "sharp" mean "smart" and "clever"? If so, why is Jack's answer smart?

Answer (score 2):

> sharp as a needle

is an idiomatic phrase. It means a person is intelligent and quick to figure things out and solve problems. The simile is that a needle's quality and usefulness is decided by how sharp it is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why is Jack's answer smart?

Comment: Intelligent, because he came up with a quick correct answer.

Comment: I wonder if what correct answer is. That is to say, is the correct answer to be five in total? If so, Jack's answer was no problem like "One in one hand and three in another hand and one in your mouth."?

Comment: It is not that his solution is the only one (obviously not), but *how* it was presented, quick and certainly possible.

Answer (score 1):

*As sharp as a tack* means the same. For example, she's very witty-she's *as sharp as a tack*; also, as *sharp as a razor* does work as well.

These similes are also used literally to mean "having a keen cutting edge" and have largely replaced the earlier [*sharp as a needle* or thorn](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sharp+as+a+tack). The first dates from about 1900, the variant rootes in the mid-1800s. Wasn't the "Jack and the Beanstalk" tale written in those times of lore?

Anyways, this expession CAN be used nowardays. Why not, once *sharp* does mean *clever* or whatsoever (a multiple usage of the adjective it is, isn't it)?

Comment: *nowadays*, maybe?